# Question about John Lee's proof on smooth manifold with boundary admitting a boundary defining function

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I have an issue with the following proof. Here, $f_a$ is defined only on $U_a$. So to make the function $f=\sum_a \psi_a f_a$ defined on $M$, we need to extend $\psi_a f_a$ to $M$. We do this (as in Lemma 2.26) by making it $0$ on $M \backslash supp \psi_a$. However, note that we have not extended $f_a$ to $M$.

This is what I assume is done in the below proof. But then my problem is that we cannot make sense of $f_a(p)d\psi_a|_p(v)$ in the sum. I can see that since $p$ is a boundary point, it only belongs to a boundary chart so we must have $f_a(p)=0$. However, what happens if $U_a$ is an interior chart? Then how do we make sense of $f_a(p)$ below? So how can we apply the product rule when we have not extended $f_a$ to the whole of $M$?

I am really confused with this because for $U_a$ interior, we have $f_a(p)=1$, so I don't get why the first term in parentheses is $0$.

To consider the differential of $f$ at $p$, we need to look at $f$ in a neighborhood of $f$ that intersects finitely many $\supp \psi_a$. How do we ensure that the $\psi_a$'s here are the ones subordinate to the boundary charts?

Also how do we know that there is at least one $\alpha $ for which the second term is positive?
[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all, it is completely standard to take $\psi_\alpha f_\alpha = 0$ everywhere that $\psi_\alpha = 0$.  We're only interested in the derivative computation when $p\in\partial M$. So no interior chart $U_\alpha$ is in play here (i.e., every $\alpha$ for which $U_\alpha$ is an interior chart we have $\psi_\alpha = 0$ in a neighborhood of $p$) and so your point is moot.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks Ted I actually just figured that point out. But  I still can't prove why at least one of the $\psi_a(p)>0$ in the second term. So it's clear from your comments that we consider $f=\sum_a \psi_a f_a$ with the indices belonging to boundary charts only. It seems like we then use $\sum_a \psi_a (p)=1$, but how can I ensure that the $a$'s that make $\psi_a(p)>0$ will be included here?

Comment: Because it's a partition of unity!! For every $p$, whether in the interior or in the boundary, we must have $\sum \psi_\alpha(p) = 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin You mean $=1$? My question explicitly is this: When we look at the derivative of $f=\sum_a \psi_a f_a$ at $p$, we consider the sum in some neighborhood of $p$ that intersects finitely many $supp \psi_a$. Your first argument ensures that these neighborhoods can be considered to intersect only those $\psi_a$ corresponding to boundary charts, so say $f(x) = \sum_1^k \psi_n f_n(x)$. From here how do we know that at least one $1\le j \le k$ has $\psi_j(p)>0$ using $\sum \psi_a(p)=1$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I mean those $\psi_a$ corresponding to boundary charts for which $\psi_a(p)>0$ may not be included in the above $\psi_1, \dots, \psi_k$. I don't know how to guarantee that they do.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I think the confusion here is why we can apply the Leibniz rule when the $f_\alpha$ are not defined on $M$.  $f_\alpha(p)$ makes no sense when $U_\alpha$ is an interior chart.

Comment: @SteveD Yes that was the initial confusion. Then I realized that $\psi_a f_a$ is $0$ in a neighborhood of $p$ if $U_a$ is an interior chart, so we can ignore the interior charts when we consider the sum for $f$ near $p$. But then I can't figure out why we must have $\psi_a(p)>0$ for some index $a$.

Comment: Yes, 0 was a typo. I don’t understand your point. How are the $\psi_\alpha(p)$ adding up to $1$?

Comment: @TedShifrin How do I get a contradiction if I assume that for $f(x)=\sum_1^k \psi_n f_n(x)$, I have $\psi_n(p)=0$ for all $1\le n \le k$? All I know is that this is defined on some neighborhood $N$ of $p$ for which $N \cap supp \psi_n \neq \emptyset$. Isn't it possible that the $\psi_a$'s for which $\psi_a(p)>0$ is not included among this $\psi_1, \dots, \psi_k$?

Comment: Well the $f_\alpha$ for boundary charts **also** aren't defined on $M$ so applying the Leibniz rule still makes no sense.

Comment: @SteveD That is true... A possible solution I think is since we have a neighborhood in which the sum involves only finitely many $f_n$'s from the interior chart $U_n$, we can further restrict the neighborhood to the intersections with all these $U_n$'s?

Comment: I think it's more involved than that. You have a nbhd intersecting finitely many supports. Cut away those coming from interior charts. Now take the finitely many supports containing $p$, and intersect this new nbhd with the corresponding boundary charts. **Now** you have an open set where each $f_\alpha$ comes from a boundary chart, and is defined on the whole nbhd, so Leibniz makes sense. Since each support containing $p$ is represented by one of these $f_\alpha$, you're also guaranteed the sum of $\phi_\alpha(p)$ is still $1$.

Comment: @SteveD That is precisely what I had in mind, except that I accidentally put interior chart instead of boundary chart.